# Dynamically added content doesn't scroll correctly (JTextPane inside JScrollPane)

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

The following behavior of `JScrollPane(JTextPane)` seems to be above my paygrade:

I have added a textPane inside a scrollPane to my frame.

```
    textPane = new JTextPane();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
```

If I set the content of the textPane via `textPane.setText("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM")`, textPane is expanding and scrollPane is doing its job correctly.

[image]

However, if I use `textPane` to redirect `out` and `err` using [MessageConsole](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/), it does some sort of word-wrap.  I check the source of MessageConsole and it does not alter any word-wrap behavior of `textPane`.  It appears that `textPane.getDocument().insertString(.)` causes `textPane` to not expand properly.

```
    MessageConsole mc = new MessageConsole(textPane);
    mc.redirectOut();
    mc.redirectErr(Color.RED, null);
    mc.setMessageLines(100);
```

[image]

How can I avoid that automatic line-break from happening, when feeding content via `textPane.getDocument().insertString(.)`?  I have been unsuccessfully trying to remove this line-break for more than 3 hours now and would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: I'd be careful about redirecting stderr and stdout to the same destination, as stderr operates on a different thread, which, if not treated careful, could result in unexpected behaviour. The problem is knowing when stderr has completed dumping content, which might require some kind of consolidating process, where a small delay between output is required before the current message is pushed to the UI - I'd use a "messaging" queue here, but that's just me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, when you add a long string of text with no spaces, there is no place for the text to be split to a new line so it appears that the preferred width becomes the width of the long line of text.

There is no need for the text on all the other lines to wrap since they fit in the preferred width.

However, in the second case, there are spaces so the default behaviour of the text pane is to wrap text once the viewport is full.

This wrapping is caused by the default implementation of the `Scrollable` interface for the JTextPane. The default implementation of the `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` method returns `true`, which basically attempts to fit all the text in the width of the viewport, causing it to wrap when possible.

If you don't want the text to wrap then check out [No Wrap Text Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/). It shows how you can change the default `Scrollable` behaviour of the text pane by having the `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` method return `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much;  will check it out now.